# How many solutions in the nonnegative integers does $a + b + c = 30$ have if $a, b, c \leq 20$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Find the number of ordered triples of nonnegative integers $a, b,$ and $c$ such that $a+b+c=30$ and $a, b,$ and $c$ are all less than or equal to $20$. Can that result be generalized?

I adapted a combinatorics problem to create that question The original problem was, "Three different boxes have $20$ bottles each. All the bottles in one box have the same color, but bottles of different boxes have different colors.  How many ways can you pick the bottles from the boxes so that you pick $30$ in total?"

Answer (score 2):

First, let's count all of the possibilities of $a,b,c$, not including the constraint of $\leq20$. We can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to find the total number of ways to pick $a,b,c$ is ${32\choose2}=496$.

Next, we know that at most, one of the numbers can be greater than 20 at a time. So, let's count the number of ways that can happen. We have three variables to choose from to be greater than 20, and then, we can assign 21 of the "units" to that variable to enforce it being greater than 20.

Hence, our new constraint is $a+b+c=9$, which by stars and bars is ${11\choose2}=55$.

So, our final answer is $$496-3\cdot55=\color{red}{331}$$

Comment: I guess the answer has to be $331$ since $496$ was not an option. But I thought that the answer had to be a múltiple of  6 since if $(a, b, c)$ is a possible all permutations of it are also a valid solution, but maybe it isn't because for some ordered pairs $a$ could be equal to $b$ and then some permutation would be the same as the original

Comment: @Vmimi It has to be a multiple of 6, except that the combination $(10,10,10)$ has no permutations. Hence, it has to be 1+ a multiple of 6.

Comment: I didn't understand the second condition, how do you get it?

Comment: The final constraint wouldn't be $a+b+c=9$?